# What is the loss function which corresponds to a log-logistic accelerated failure time model?

Tags: r, regression, survival

What is the loss function which corresponds to a log-logistic accelerated failure time model? To fit a model and identify candidate beta values, we typically minimize a loss function, but I have been unable to find out anything about the loss function in this case. Please explain.

Comment: it is the log-likelihood